# Create a crontab script with curl

Tags: linux, cron, curl

Trying to set a cronjob to use with curl.
Want to update IP on noip.com.
The command below gets the IP from noip.com but does not update it with my servers ip.
I mean: when the IP is not updated then I get the old one:

```
curl -X GET 'https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update' --header "Authorization: Basic $(base64 <<< $xxxxxxx:$xxxxxx)" -d "hostname=$xxxxx.ddns.net"
```

this command below poduces error `sh: GET: command not found`

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl-X GET 'https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update' --header "Authorization: Basic <$xxxxx:$xxxxx>" -d 'hostname=<hostname>.xxxxxx.ddns.net'
```

Need help for an appropriate script

Comment: Why does the second command have an `ExecStart=` in front of it?

Comment: Actually I have copied from a forum :) don't know its accuracy

Answer (score 0):

On a modern Linux system, you do not want to use `crontab`, but systemd timers.

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/updateip.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Update IP

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl -X GET 'https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update' --header "Authorization: Basic <$xxxxx:$xxxxx>" -d 'hostname=<hostname>.xxxxxx.ddns.net'
```

Now you add a timer in `/etc/systemd/system/updateip.timer` with the following contents, to run every 10 minutes:

```
[Unit]
Description=Update IP every 10 minutes

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/10
```

Enable the timer by running `systemctl start updateip.timer`

Comment: I did but IP on noip is not updated.When running ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl -X GET 'https://dynupdate.no-ip.com................ I get:X command not found.The reason for opening this thread was that there was a certişficate error which could not be reproduced by noip support.https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am4yMVdZjYGSgYwp5tnXweWVLR5JLQ       today I did not see this error but Ithere was no IP update: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am4yMVdZjYGSgYwyHUu-aSnX5eRI2w

Comment: Solved.............