# Curl command what do I make wrong?

Tags: curl, syntax, noip

I get:

```
root@dm820:~# ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl'https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update' --header "Authorization: Basic <$xxxx:$xxx>" -d 'hostname=<hostname>.xxxx.ddns.net'
-sh: --header: command not found
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where did you get this line? It's not a command, but a snipped from systemd service.

Answer (score 1):

> what do I make wrong?
>
> ```
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/curl'https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update' --header "Authorization: Basic <$xxxx:$xxx>" -d 'hostname=<hostname>.xxxx.ddns.net'
> ```

1. You're defining `ExecStart` variable and trying to run `--header`. The syntax is like

   ```
   foo=bar some_command option1 option2
   ```
2. You're using the full path `/usr/bin/curl`. Unless you know it's right and you need the full path, you should rely on your `$PATH` and use just `curl`.
3. You have no space after `curl`.
4. You're trying to run `curl` as root.
5. You're running a command (like random code from the Internet?) *you apparently don't understand **as root***.

To fix:

- Write 100 times "I won't run commands I don't understand as root". :)
- Drop `ExecStart=`, it's a part of systemd syntax.
- Use just `curl`.
- Put a space after `curl`.

It will be like

```
curl 'https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update' --header "Authorization: Basic <$xxxx:$xxx>" -d 'hostname=<hostname>.xxxx.ddns.net'
```

where `<$xxxx:$xxx>` and `<hostname>` are still placeholders you need to change to something valid.

Comment: To simplify things a bit more, it would be like `curl https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update --user '$xxxx:$xxx' -d 'hostname=<hostname>.xxxx.ddns.net'`

Comment: @grawity Frankly I don't know `curl` and such to tell if you're right. The answer is now community wiki, so please improve it freely.

Comment: Thanks.Yes it's from internet :https://superuser.com/questions/1380720/create-a-crontab-script-with-curl   :)  Shall I write down all 100 or can I copy paste :) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this from the command line and not from `systemd`, you have to run it like this:

```
curl 'https://dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update' --header "Authorization: Basic <$xxxx:$xxx>" -d 'hostname=<hostname>.xxxx.ddns.net'
```

Comment: another layman question :) then:How do I run it from system d ?(I want to run it from system d but as it did not work out I have asked once more)

Comment: Ask a new question and clarify what you want to do ;) Please review https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Solved..........