# Why this hard-to-understand 'find' command broke my system?

Tags: find, rm

I am using archlinux and I was trying to delete core dumps file to save space on the root partition.

I stupidly ran this which I found in internet without really understanding it:

```
sudo find / -xdev -name core -ls -o -path "/lib*" -prune -exec rm {} \;
```

from what I understand so far. It will delete everything under root '/' that has the exact name 'core' except anything under '/lib'

and this is the output I got

```
 399883 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 21 18:33 /usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/litarvan/packages/$sdk/lib/core
401640 4 drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Sep 21 18:33 /usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/litarvan/packages/angular2/src/core
992335 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/log/core
999740 4 drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core
999834 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/core
999557 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/phoenix/core
992045 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/hana/fwd/core
992030 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/hana/core
991963 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/geometry/multi/core
991928 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/geometry/core
991626 4 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/beast/experimental/core
991622 4 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/beast/core
991735 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/contract/detail/inlined/core
991731 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/contract/core
1000174 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/xpressive/detail/core
991744 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 5 14:36 /usr/include/boost/core
1062959 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Dec 6 01:31 /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ranger/core
1088768 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 22 21:00 /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/core
450582 4 drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Dec 6 01:07 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.0/lib/rspec/core
1008621 4 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/sound/core
1008442 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/usb/core
1007844 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/infiniband/core
1008479 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/core
1007786 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/tinydrm/core
1008033 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/mmc/core
1008005 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/memstick/core
1008133 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core
1008569 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 14:03 /usr/lib/modules/4.19.10-arch1-1-ARCH/kernel/net/core
415080 4 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep 9 09:36 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk3/wx/lib/pubsub/core
1074158 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 7 03:10 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/radialnet/core
```

So, all of the matches are directory, and because I use `rm` without the `-r` option, it should not delete directories, which means it should delete nothing.

However, after I ran the command, most of the things in my system broke, e.g., zsh, i3. and when I reboot my PC, I got a kernel panic, bad rip value or something.

I could reinstall again since I have separate root and home partition. But I'm very curious why it broke the system.

Comment: Short answer: you need to be very *very **very*** careful of ``find`` commands that contain ``-o``. Like you would if a snake offered you a mushroom to eat.

Comment: I know `-o` means 'logical or' now, but still confused about the `-prune` option. Did I just delete everything that doesn't have `core` and under lib or? everything except files under `/lib' and have `core` in the name?

Comment: Hmm.  I took a quick look at the command in your question and I thought I understood what was happening.  On closer examination, I don’t understand; at least not fully.  Unfortunately, I don’t have time to investigate right now.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Look at [Why does ‘find’ in Linux skip expected results when ‘-o’ is used?](https://superuser.com/q/966227/150988), [Why does the “-or” flag to GNU find cause my expression to evaluate in an unexpected way?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183879/23408), ['find' with '-o' and '-exec chown' not working as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/313957/23408) and [find command: -or option doesn’t work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143983/23408), and see whether they help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some relevant fragments of [`find` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> `-xdev`
>   The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause find not to continue descending past directories that have a different device ID […]. If any `-xdev` primary is specified, it shall apply to the entire expression even if the `-xdev` primary would not normally be evaluated.
>
> `-prune`
>   The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause find not to descend the current pathname if it is a directory. […]
>
> […]
>
> The primaries can be combined using the following operators (in order of decreasing precedence):
>
> […]
>
> `expression  [-a]  expression`
>   Conjunction of primaries; the AND operator is implied by the juxtaposition of two primaries or made explicit by the optional `-a` operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is false.
>
> `expression  -o  expression`
>   Alternation of primaries; the OR operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is true.

Now your command (just to have it in sight):

> ```
> find / -xdev -name core -ls -o -path "/lib*" -prune -exec rm {} \;
> ```

Some conclusions and facts:

1. `-xdev` applies to everything, even to the part after `-o`.
2. Because juxtaposition (or `-a`) precedes `-o`, your command is like `( expression1 ) -o ( expression2 )` (compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183880/108618)).
3. All the output you saw came from `-ls`.
4. Whenever `-ls` worked, the first expression was true, so the second one was not evaluated (which means matches you saw were not removed).
5. `-path "/lib*"` matches these objects:

   - directories with names matching `lib*` directly in `/`,
   - non-directories with names matching `lib*` directly in `/`,
   - <strike>all objects inside directories from the first bullet point</strike> (not in your case, because of `-prune`).

So `rm` was invoked for any object that fulfills all of the following conditions:

1. It belongs to the same filesystem as `/` (because of `-xdev`).
2. It's not named `core` (because of how `-o` works).
3. It's directly in `/` and its name matches `lib*`.

I run this in my Kubuntu to print such objects:

```
find / -xdev -name core -o -path "/lib*" -prune -print
```

and the result was

```
/lib
/lib64
/lib32
```

Each of these is a directory, sole `rm` (without `-r`) cannot remove it. I'm pretty sure in my case your original command wouldn't break the system. However *if* any matching object was not a directory, `rm` would most likely remove it.

[FHS - Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf) says:

> `/lib32` and `/lib64` might be the library directories, and `/lib` a symlink to one of them.

I *guess* your `/lib` may have been a symlink and `rm` had no problem removing it. This location is for essential shared libraries and kernel modules (see FHS or [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74652/108618)), no wonder you broke your system. I can't be sure there was no other `lib*` non-directory which was also removed; but if I'm right about `/lib` then *maybe* recreating the symlink is all you need to fix the system.

In [another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1381317/432690) the first advice is

> Write 100 times "I won't run commands I don't understand as root". :)

but it looks like you have already learnt your lesson.